# Meteor deploy Bcrypt error Invoking deployment process

Tags: meteor, bcrypt

I want to deploy a meteor app (v1.2) to digital ocean. I am using [MUP](https://github.com/zodern/meteor-up) with this [tutorial](https://gist.github.com/jamiewilson/4e1d28f9a200cb34ad59).

When I run `mup deploy` ***verbose*** I get this error (see below). I tried this as well being how i am on linux. `meteor build myAppHere --architecture os.linux.x86_64` . But I still get the error.

Any ideas?

```
Started TaskList: Deploy app 'myAppHere' (linux)
[162.243.58.84] - Uploading bundle
[162.243.58.84] - Uploading bundle: SUCCESS
[162.243.58.84] - Setting up Environment Variables
[162.243.58.84] - Setting up Environment Variables: SUCCESS
[162.243.58.84] - Invoking deployment process
[162.243.58.84] x Invoking deployment process: FAILED
    
    -----------------------------------STDERR-----------------------------------
    ile=node.lib',
    gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/opt/myAppHere/tmp/bundle/programs/server/npm/npm-bcrypt/node_modules/bcrypt',
    gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
    gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
    gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
    gyp info spawn args   'build',
    gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.' ]
    gyp info spawn make
    gyp info spawn args [ 'BUILDTYPE=Release', '-C', 'build' ]
    gyp info ok 
    npm WARN package.json meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No description
    npm WARN package.json meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No repository field.
    npm WARN package.json meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No README data
    stop: Unknown instance: 
      % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                     Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 81: Connection refused
    Latest deployment failed! Reverted back to the previous version.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is your node version? Most probably installed nodejs version is old. You can try with "nodeVersion": "0.10.40" in your mup.json

Comment: yeah i tried that a couple of moments ago and i got it to work.